# How to build a VS 2010 extension using VS 2013?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

Just found a wonderful [tool](https://github.com/tfsbuildextensions/BuildManager) for TFS build management and did some [modifications](https://github.com/yingang/BuildManager/tree/uih) to fit the build system in our company.

Here comes my prolbem, the code is maintained in VS2013 while the R&D environment is still using VS2010, is it possible to build VS extension for an old version of VS?

ps. failed to found anything usefull after some searching on the internet, any suggestion would be appriecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you need to use the same version to build your extension that you are targeting...

Answer (score 1):

You can use VS 2013 to maintain an extension for VS 2010. Just keep v1 of .vsixmanifest and reference VS 2010 dlls (usually having v10). It is highly recommended to initially create an extension project in VS 2010, but once it is working you can maintain it in a higher version of Visual Studio. (I personally use VS 2015 to maintain my extensions targeting VS 2010+).